# ACCESS DENIED NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I have a windows servce calling a DLL that should manipulate a file.
When I try to manipulate the file I have this error message:
ACCESS DENIED   NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE (From Filemon).
This issue is not here on a Windows 7 machine, but on all Windows XP machines.

Comment: What is in the stack for access denied operation?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file in question?  Is another program holding the file open?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was the file had wrong permissions. The windows service user was not able to write it. I had to fix this issue in my setup program.